# How to add chrome bookmarks to Windows 7 favorites folder (where IE favorites live)

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks

I just switched to Windows 7 and love the taskbar and library features.

If I make a desktop shortcut to a webpage, then it becomes searchable from the taskbar (i.e., press the Win/meta key and type the shortcut's name and it pops up). The IE bookmarks/favorites already come with shortcuts in your "Favorites" folder.

Can I programatically do this with my chrome shortcuts? My first thought was to export bookmarks to IE, but I can't find an option in IE that allows me to export bookmarks/favorites as shortcuts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh. I should have tinkered more first.

1. delete IE favorites (in browser or folder) -- not required, but this is a new laptop and I don't need the defaults
2. export bookmarks from chrome to an html file
3. import this file to IR favorites from the favorites menu in IE
4. right click on the favorites folder in explorer and make a new library

Now I can search chrome bookmarks from the taskbar. I still have chrome as default, so when I search from the taskbar, I can open the page in chrome, whether chrome is running or not.

Comment: Duh? whats that about?

Comment: I answered my own question, and thought it was pretty obvious when I finally got it. I just switched to Windows and find everything counterintuitive... until I do it, then it's obvious.